# Is it correct to say "In this paper we will prove that..." in academic papers?

Tags: will-be-going

Is it correct to say "In this paper we will prove that..."?
I think in academic papers we should use "be going to" instead of "will", because "will" is used to describe something at the moment of speaking, not to describe something which has already been planned or arranged.

Comment: You think wrongly. ‘We are going to prove’ and ‘we will prove’ are both future tense, but the former is a) more imminent in time (in just a moment, we are going to prove) and b) less formal in style. There is nothing wrong with saying, “In this paper we will prove that …”, although it is perhaps somewhat presumptuous. A more common wording (at least within the humanities) is, “In this paper, we _hope to_ prove that …”.

Comment: Customs differ among academic fields. Check the literature. However, in scientific fields, the word _prove_ cannot be used in a claim; this is only OK in mathematics, logic, and philosophy in a strict sense. As [Gregory Bateson puts it](http://www.virtualsynapses.com/2012/08/science-never-really-proves-anything.html#.UnvlVeWKbYs), "Science Never Really Proves Anything".

Answer (score 3):

In my classes the standard was to say to say "this paper will prove," when you submitted research proposals, but to say "this paper proves" in the final paper.